# linux command line: passing wrong argument?

Tags: c++

I'm debugging my C++ code on Ubuntu which I execute as `./main path < input.txt`

`argv[1]` should contain a string "path" which verified by GDB below.

However, the program always jumps over my first condition even though `argv[1] == "path"` should return true.

Any idea?

```
...
(gdb) n
181     if(argv[1] == "path")
(gdb) p argv[1]
$1 = 0xbffffba3 "path"
(gdb) n
183     else if(argc == 1)
(gdb)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c). Although this question was in C++, the question I linked to applies to both C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the two strings are the same, they occupy a different location in memory. When it is checking whether `argv[1]` is equal to a fixed-string `"path"`, it is not doing it character-by-character: it is looking to see whether the pointer to the fixed-string `"path"` is the same as the `argv[1]` variable passed into `main()`, which it is not.

You need to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to test the equality of those two strings:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "path") == 0) { /* they match */ }
```

Comment: Doesn't C++ overload `==` for string comparisons though?

Comment: If only! Sadly, C++ tries to keep as much compatibility with original C as possible, and since `==` in C would check the pointers against each other, C++ does not want to break this style. You might be able to overload it yourself, and maybe `std::string` has some better operations, but remember that neither `argv[1]` nor `"path"` are type `std::string`: they are a `char*` or `const char*` array, respectively.